# How to successfully get all the tweets for one user with tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to pull all the tweets from USATODAY's twitter account. But, I keep hitting the rate limits when doing so. How do I start from where I left off of after I hit the rate limit?

For example, there are a total of 100k tweets. My code gets the first 3000 then hits the limit. How do I start at 3001 when my limit resets and so on until I can get all 100k?

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id='USATODAY').items():
    print(tweet)
```

Comment: I am afraid if you would be able to retrieve all 100k posts that's a huge number and I guess there is a limit as how many tweets can you retrieve using twitter API.

Comment: that cursor that's being returned and then you call `items()` on it.  Try getting that cursor, it likely has the cookie required to continue where you left off.  Or you need to space out your API calls with a sleep so as not to bump up against the rate limiter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outside of API limits, only the most recent 3000 tweets are available to anyone other than the account holder, even in the web interface. If you want the tweets before that, you'd need access to the archive.

Comment: thanks, i double checked with twitter's documentation

Comment: @manglano does it mean account holder can retrieve all their 100k tweets using tweepy?